# Google Apps Script (JavaScript) Regex splitting Spreadsheet Cell References

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm currently looking to produce a function that splits a string spreadsheet cell reference into the column/row (letter/number) components.

The formula I'm currently working with is:

```
function reTest() {
  var re = /(\$?[A-Za-z]+)(\$?[0-9]+)/g;
  var cells = ['A1', 'AA1', 'A12', 'A$1', 'AA$1', 'A$12', '$A1', '$AA1', '$A12', '$A$1', '$AA$1', '$A$12'];
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(re.exec(cells[i]));
  }
}
```

My desired output (albeit truncated) would be along the lines of:

```
['A', '1']
['AA', '1']
['A', '12']
['A', '$1']
etc...
```

However, currently my output is:

```
[A1, A, 1]
null
[A12, A, 12]
null
[AA$1, AA, $1]
null
[$A1, $A, 1]
null
[$A12, $A, 12]
null
[$AA$1, $AA, $1]
null
```

I'll be frank and say I'm a bit of a Regex Novice, but I can't understand why this is not working as expected.

All points are welcomed, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `g` global modifier, and only grab Group 1 and Group 2 captured texts:

This code:

```
function reTest() {
  var re = /(\$?[A-Za-z]+)(\$?[0-9]+)/;
  var cells = ['A1', 'AA1', 'A12', 'A$1', 'AA$1', 'A$12', '$A1', '$AA1', '$A12', '$A$1', '$AA$1', '$A$12'];
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var m = re.exec(cells[i]);
    if (m) {
      Logger.log([m[1], m[2]]);
    }
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
[17-08-04 18:27:18:994 CEST] [A, 1]
[17-08-04 18:27:18:995 CEST] [AA, 1]
[17-08-04 18:27:18:995 CEST] [A, 12]
[17-08-04 18:27:18:996 CEST] [A, $1]
[17-08-04 18:27:18:996 CEST] [AA, $1]
[17-08-04 18:27:18:997 CEST] [A, $12]
[17-08-04 18:27:18:998 CEST] [$A, 1]
[17-08-04 18:27:18:998 CEST] [$AA, 1]
[17-08-04 18:27:18:999 CEST] [$A, 12]
[17-08-04 18:27:18:999 CEST] [$A, $1]
[17-08-04 18:27:19:000 CEST] [$AA, $1]
[17-08-04 18:27:19:000 CEST] [$A, $12]
```

Or, you may also tell the regex engine to match the whole string by adding anchors:

```
var re = /^(\$?[A-Za-z]+)(\$?[0-9]+)$/;
```

Why do you need to remove the global modifier: when you add `g`, the regex `.lastIndex` property is advanced to the position where the match ends, thus the next match will be looked for from the position that may be already past the text where the pattern can match.

Comment: Excellent! I also found a solution for this just as you posted this which I've posted above, is there any reason to choose one way over the other?

Comment: The `/(\$?[A-Za-z]+)|(\$?[0-9]+)/g` will match multiple occurrences of `(\$?[A-Za-z]+)` or `(\$?[0-9]+)` patterns anywhere in the string. If there are tywo groups in the string, I'd suggest `/^(\$?[A-Za-z]+)(\$?[0-9]+)$/`. No match will be found in `$12()abc$A`

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out a minor adjustment to my code got it working.

Introduced a pipe operator into the regex expression and substituting the `RegExp.exec` for `string.match`.

```
function reTest() {
  var re = /(\$?[A-Za-z]+)|(\$?[0-9]+)/g;
  var cells = ['A1', 'AA1', 'A12', 'A$1', 'AA$1', 'A$12', '$A1', '$AA1', '$A12', '$A$1', '$AA$1', '$A$12'];
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(cells[i].match(re));
  }
}
```